# Python selenium send_keys not working on password field

Tags: python, django, selenium

send_keys() works with the username field but not the password field. Here is my code:

```
class PpeLiveTest(LiveServerTestCase):


    # test that the first cell for the tennessee total row is the correct sum 
    # for quince and allenbrooke for the incentives table

    def test_sums_incentives_tennessee(self):


        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")

        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

        driver.get('https://[redacted]/pr-run-ppe?group=MS%2FTN%2FLA&check_date=05%2F01%2F2022')

        # login first

        username_element = driver.find_element_by_id('id_login')
        username_element.send_keys('[redacted]')

        password_element = driver.find_element_by_id('id_password')
        password_element.send_keys(os.environ.get('ADMIN_PASS'))

        login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/form/button')
        login_button.click()
```

I look at driver.page_source in the console when running this test. It's still the login page. username is filled with the [redacted] as expected but the password field is blank. Anyone know why?

os.environ.get('ADMIN_PASS') is not blank.

password_element is the correct element that we expect

Comment: Try replacing `os.environ.get('ADMIN_PASS')` with the actual password, just to see if that works.  If it does, then it was blank in the environment...

Comment: first use `print()` to see if `os.environ.get('ADMIN_PASS')` is really not blank. Next you could run without `--headless` to see what browser is doing - maybe it shows some information on screen or it display some error JavaScript console in DevTools. And finally you could show real URL so we could see and test code with this page